# Await async function in for in loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am having a double "for in" loop where I need to scan through first car brand and all driving styles, and then download the number of documents where I have votes from users.
So the code should scan through a driving style, for example "sport" and for each of them get the number of documents in firebase (number of votes).

This is my code:

```
List<String> brands = [
'ferrari',
'porshe',
'lamborgini',
'bugatti',
'bentley',
];

List<String> drivingStyles = [
'sport',
'comfort',
'offroad',
];

    Future getVotes(String brand, String drivingStyle) async {
try {
  for (String brand in brands) {
    for (String drivingStyle in drivingStyles) {
      var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('survey')
          .doc('car_survey')
          .collection('summer')
          .where('brand', isEqualTo: brand)
          .where('drivingStyle', isEqualTo: drivingStyle);
      var querySnapshot = await query.get();
      var numberOfVotes = querySnapshot.docs.length;
      
      print('brand: $brand, drivingStyle: $drivingStyle');
       //print('$numberOfVotes');

    }
  }

} catch (e) {
  print('getVotes ERROR: $e');
}
```

When I just print the names of brands and driving styles (result of for in loops) it looks perfect, like this:

```
I/flutter ( 4723): brand: ferrari, drivingStyle: sport
I/flutter ( 4723): brand: ferrari, drivingStyle: comfort
I/flutter ( 4723): brand: ferrari, drivingStyle: offroad|
etc...
```

which is exactly what I expect,
however after activating `await query.get()` I am getting one driving style for one car brand, until the end of car brands styles, and then over again with the next driving style through all car brands - that is opposite what I need and I do not understand why it changes after activating `await query.get()`. I basically receive this:

```
I/flutter (12137): brand: ferrari, drivingStyle: sport
I/flutter (12137): brand: porshe, drivingStyle: sport
I/flutter (12137): brand: lamborghini, drivingStyle: sport
I/flutter (12137): brand: bugatti, drivingStyle: sport
I/flutter (12137): brand: bentley, drivingStyle: sport

I/flutter (12137): brand: ferrari, drivingStyle: comfort
I/flutter (12137): brand: porshe, drivingStyle: comfort
etc...
```

I need to read value of all driving styles for one brand and then save it as values.

It seems like I am having an issue with awaiting Future in `for in` loop. Can you please have a look and tell me what am I doing wrong?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks okay. Can we see `getVotes` after you've included your firebase function and where you print numberOfVotes.

Comment: Hi @PeterO. and thanks for your input. I have just updated the question.

Comment: I just ran your function and I noticed something. The value passed to `getVotes` function is being updated by the for statement. Is this the intended action? Could that be where the error is from? Because I ran your code without passing any parameter to `getVotes` and it worked as intended.

Comment: You mean values `brand` and `drivingStyle` passed to `getVotes` from outside? How are they updated by for statement? There was no intention for it. Based on those values I just need to read how many votes are there in the collection (querySnapshot.docs.length) so when Firestore path is changing, the number (int) I am getting is being processed further...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    List<String> brands = [];
    List<String> drivingStyles = [];
    for (String brand in brands) {
      await Future.forEach(drivingStyles, (String drivingStyle) async {
        var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('survey')
            .doc('car_survey')
            .collection('summer')
            .where('brand', isEqualTo: brand)
            .where('drivingStyle', isEqualTo: drivingStyle);
        var querySnapshot = await query.get();
        var numberOfVotes = querySnapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve anything. The result is the same as with `await query.get()` function activated in my code, even though the async function is inactive.

Comment: Well youll understand if youll receive that future value output. youre debugging your code based on printed value which is not asynchronous value.